# UV Editor, Blurred vertex, edge, face UV selection

Tags: uv-image-editor

Is there any reason when I select vertexes, edges or faces in the UV editor, the selection marker blurs to extends to its surrounding elements? I am not aware of having touched anything to get that. Apparently, it doesn't affect the way the selected elements behave, but It is visually very annoying.

Thanks so much.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The blur is to indicate what edges the vertex is (and more importantly isn't) connected to. This can be very useful when two vertices are on top of each other for whatever reason.

Comment: It is weird though it doesn't happen to me on my previous blender setup, in 2.90.1

It happens to me in my current working version of blender 2.91

Comment: Hmm, check user preferences. Sometimes I've forgotten I changed something and then the settings didn't port.

Comment: Yeah... that's is precisely my problem. I think there is something changed in user preferences but I don't know what is it.

That is what my question is about pretty much...